# October CMS User plugin weird behavior

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, octobercms

I have installed the user plugin on my local environment. Then I embedded the accounts component on my login page.

The form is displayed correctly but I am facing a weird issue.

Scenario:
1) I create a new user with the registration form .

2) Upon user creation the same page  loads again with the user registration form.

3)But when I refresh the same page the second time it then displays the user profile page.

So I am curious about this weird behavior I am also not getting any errors on console.

I have created a custom theme for my website .Am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added these lines on your plugins' controller config_form.yaml 
I got this sample from a custom customer plugin. Make sure to add valid urls to following code. Add user profile page link with /:id to redirectClose inside ''.

```
defaultRedirect: custom/customer
create:
  redirect: 'custom/customer/customers/update/:id'
  redirectClose: custom/customer/customers
update:
  redirect: custom/customer/customers
  redirectClose: custom/customer/customers
```

It's easy to find answers when you add your current code snippets to the question.